# how to check javascript watch is running or not?

Tags: javascript

I am using the below javascript clock to record the timing. I am starting this clock on button click. Now, I need to alert user if this clock is not running. How to check this running state of clock?

```
    function markPresent() {
        window.markDate = new Date();
        updateClock();
    }

    function updateClock() {
        var currDate = new Date();
        var diff = currDate - markDate;
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = format(diff / 1000);
        setTimeout(function () { updateClock() }, 1000);
    }

    function format(seconds) {
        var numhours = parseInt(Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600), 10);
        var numminutes = parseInt(Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60), 10);
        var numseconds = parseInt((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60, 10);
        return ((numhours < 10) ? "0" + numhours : numhours)
            + ":" + ((numminutes < 10) ? "0" + numminutes : numminutes)
            + ":" + ((numseconds < 10) ? "0" + numseconds : numseconds);
    }

<div id="divtimer" style="text-align:center">
  <p id="test"></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick=" markPresent()">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: not running because what? The user never pressed the button? Why not just start the clock automatically, if it needs to be running?

Comment: No, it should start after button click only. I am recording the time user takes to do some activity which he can proceed after starting this clock only.

Comment: so if the user can't start the activity unless they started the clock, then what's the problem? I'm struggling to see why you need a warning system...just stop them from doing whatever it is until they have pressed the button to start the clock

Comment: thanks..I didn't notice the other way..in a hurry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think your issue is simple, but while taking a look at your code I found other issues I'd like to mention so you can improve your JavaScript skills.

## Global things first.

> Always keep this in mind with JavaScript, since it's a good practice to define first what you will use later on in your code. Your code doesn't have this, so if it for some reason needs to be implemented somewhere else, you could have a bad time.

#### HTML

Since our HTML won't change a lot, lets keep clear that our HTML will be this:

```
<div id="divtimer" style="text-align:center">
    <p id="test"></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="clock">Start</button>
</div>
```

The only change for our HTML was adding the `id="clock"` attribute to the button.

#### JavaScript

So, for example, lets define every DOM element we will use, the clock handler and the control variables first:

```
var clockDiv = document.querySelector("#test"),
    button = document.querySelector("#clock"),
    clock = null, //Define a global variable for the clock
    isRunning = false, //You can view if clock is running from every scope 
    initTime = null;// Initial time of the clock
```

#### Why a global variable for the clock?

To keep safe the balance between app functionality and app performance, we need to define a variable for the `setInterval()` function so you can stop it whenever you want, instead of keeping the function running even if you stopped the clock.

---

## Handling the button.

In order to prevent the execution of the code when the DOM isn't ready, we can call an event listener on the global variable we already defined for the clock button:

```
button.addEventListener("click",Clock);
```

Yes, as simple as that. This will call the `Clock()` function every time the button is clicked.

---

## Handling the Clock()

This is what I was talking about. Since we already defined what we will need to use in the rest of the code (global variables), we can now just check in the `Clock()` function if the value of `clock===null`:

```
function Clock() {
    console.log("Called clock");
    if (clock != null) {
        //Clock is running
        console.log("Stopping clock");
        clearInterval(clock);
        clock = null;
        button.innerText = "Start";
        clockDiv.innerText = "";
        isRunning = false;
    } else {
        //Clock is not running
        console.log("Starting clock");
        setInitialTime();
        clock = setInterval(updateClock, 1000); // Starts calling updateClock, which should do what your need with the clock.
        button.innerText = "Stop"; //Changes the clock button text
        updateClock();
        isRunning = true;
    }
}
```

The button only has two functions. Stop and Start. So then we can use an `if` statement to check whether the clock has been started already or not, and do the opposite action of that. (If stopped, start it.. Else, if started, stop it.)

### NOTE:

> **Don't use innerHTML.**

It is a very bad practice in JavaScript, since using innerHTML parses everything in your string into HTML to place it on the DOM. In a small application it might not have a big effect, but in production using `innerHTML` could kill the balance between app functionality and app performance.

> Recommended use: innerText.

---

## Updating the clock.

When starting the clock, we called a function named `setInitialTime()` which its only job is to define our global variable `initTime` to the time when we clicked the button:

```
function setInitialTime() {
    initTime = new Date().getTime();
}
```

Now, to update the clock, the only thing we need to do is compare the two timestamps given and calculate the difference between:

```
function updateClock() {
    console.log("Clock update");
    let currTime = new Date().getTime(),
        diff = currTime - initTime;
    console.log(format(diff / 1000));
    clockDiv.innerText = format(diff / 1000);
}
```

And your `format()` function stays the same:

```
function format(seconds) {
    var numhours = parseInt(Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600), 10);
    var numminutes = parseInt(Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60), 10);
    var numseconds = parseInt((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60, 10);
    return ((numhours < 10) ? "0" + numhours : numhours) + ":" + ((numminutes < 10) ? "0" + numminutes : numminutes) + ":" + ((numseconds < 10) ? "0" + numseconds : numseconds);
}
```

So there you go, that would be your code with the necessary changes and suggestions I made. It works the same, but with an eye into a good performance.

> ***Note:*** You can now see the variable `isRunning` where you want to check if your clock is running or not.

### See how it works:

```js
var clockDiv = document.querySelector("#test"),
    button = document.querySelector("#clock"),
    clock = null, //Define a global variable for the clock
    isRunning = false,
    initTime = null;

button.addEventListener("click", Clock);

function Clock() {
    console.log("Called clock");
    if (clock != null) {
        //Clock is running
        console.log("Stopping clock");
        clearInterval(clock);
        clock = null;
        button.innerText = "Start";
        clockDiv.innerText = "";
        isRunning = false;
    } else {
        //Clock is not running
        console.log("Starting clock");
        setInitialTime();
        clock = setInterval(updateClock, 1000); // Starts calling updateClock, which should do what your need with the clock.
        button.innerText = "Stop"; //Changes the clock button text
        updateClock();
        isRunning = true;
    }
}

function setInitialTime() {
    initTime = new Date().getTime();
}

function updateClock() {
    console.log("Clock update");
    let currTime = new Date().getTime(),
        diff = currTime - initTime;
    console.log("Actual time is " + currTime);
    console.log("Time inited was " + initTime);
    console.log(format(diff / 1000));
    clockDiv.innerText = format(diff / 1000);
}

function format(seconds) {
    var numhours = parseInt(Math.floor(((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) / 3600), 10);
    var numminutes = parseInt(Math.floor((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) / 60), 10);
    var numseconds = parseInt((((seconds % 31536000) % 86400) % 3600) % 60, 10);
    return ((numhours < 10) ? "0" + numhours : numhours) + ":" + ((numminutes < 10) ? "0" + numminutes : numminutes) + ":" + ((numseconds < 10) ? "0" + numseconds : numseconds);
}
```

```html
<div id="divtimer" style="text-align:center">
  <p id="test"></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="clock">Start</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You made by day..A very nice explanation. Thank you so much for your efforts :) marking this an answer

Comment: Glad to know that. Always wiling to help, everything thanks to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () { checkClock() }, 2000);


var lastDiff = null;
function checkClock() {
    let currDiff = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
    if (currDiff == lastDiff) {
        alert('Clock is not running!');
    } else {
    lastDiff = currDiff;
    setTimeout(function () { checkClock() }, 2000);
}
```